# Installed a module for python but I can't call it and it seems to be locked

Tags: python, module, pycharm, python-imaging-library

I can't call the PIL module and when I go to see where it is stored the folder and its contents all have little locks round them, can anyone help?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Show us the code where you try to use PIL: "I can't call the PIL module" ; moreover do you have any error message?

Comment: It might help if you said what OS you are using, which version of Python, how you installed it, how you are trying to use it and what errors you got....